# Replacing NA values with the next value in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

I'm trying to **mutate a column** in a Dataframe using the `lag()` function as a condition **without producing `NA` values**. Let me create an example:

```
df <- data.frame("Score" = as.numeric(c("20", "10", "15", "30", "15", "10")),
             "Time" = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2"),
             "Team" = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"))
```

After that, I created a new column named `Diff` that calculates the difference of the Score of every Team:

```
 df <- df %>% 
 group_by(Team) %>% 
 mutate(Diff = Score - lag(Score))
```

My problem is that this method creates `NA` values, obviously:

```
  Score Time  Team   Diff
  20     1     A        NA
  10     2     A       -10
  15     1     B        NA
  30     2     B        15
  15     1     C        NA
  10     2     C        -5
```

My goal is to have this at the end:

```
  Score Time  Team   Diff
  20     1     A       -10
  10     2     A       -10
  15     1     B        15
  30     2     B        15
  15     1     C        -5
  10     2     C        -5
```

I've tried mutating again using the `case_when()` function to substitute the `NA` for the next value, but it also didn't work:

```
 df %>% 
 group_by(Team) %>% 
 mutate(Diff = Score - lag(Score)) %>% 
 mutate(Diff = case_when(
 NA ~ lead(Diff)
 ))
```

Anyway, how do I make the **`NA` values be replaced by the next `Diff` value?**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `fill()` after the fact:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame("Score" = as.numeric(c("20", "10", "15", "30", "15", "10")),
                 "Time" = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2"),
                 "Team" = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"))
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Team) %>% 
  mutate(Diff = Score - lag(Score)) %>% 
  fill(Diff, .direction = 'up')

df
# output
#   Score Time  Team   Diff
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1    20 1     A       -10
#2    10 2     A       -10
#3    15 1     B        15
#4    30 2     B        15
#5    15 1     C        -5
#6    10 2     C        -5
```